# Thicker border line glow for box & add labels for sub equations

Tags: equations, border, box

I am looking to add a thicker blue line to the box (potentially with a glow like feature but not essential!) I have constructed for a box containing three split equations, as well as trying to add labels to the three equations by letter i.e. 3.20a/3.20b/3.20c.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage{empheq}
  \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

  \begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[box = \fcolorbox{blue}{white}]{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \frac{\delta \rho}{\delta t} + &\nabla (\rho v) = 0 \\ 
    \rho \frac{D\textbf{v}}{Dt} &=-\nabla P + \mu \Delta \textbf{v} \\
    \rho \frac{De}{Dt} &= \frac{\delta (\rho e)}{\delta t} + \nabla (\rho e \vv{\text{V}}) 
    \end{split}
    \end{empheq}

  \end{document}
```

Attached is a photo of their current state.

Thank you again.

Josh [image]

Comment: In your MWE is missing package `esvect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{empheq, esvect}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[box = \fcolorbox{blue}{white}]{align}
\frac{\delta \rho}{\delta t} + 
    &\nabla (\rho v) = 0 \\
\rho \frac{D\textbf{v}}{Dt} 
    &=-\nabla P + \mu \Delta \textbf{v} \\
\rho \frac{De}{Dt} 
    &= \frac{\delta (\rho e)}{\delta t} + \nabla (\rho e \vv{\text{V}})
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Regarding thickness of box's edges, you can change it with `\setlength{\fboxrule}{<desired width>}`, for example:

```
    \begin{subequations}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
\begin{empheq}[box = \fcolorbox{blue}{white}]{align}
\frac{\delta \rho}{\delta t} + 
    &\nabla (\rho v) = 0 \\
\rho \frac{D\textbf{v}}{Dt} 
    &=-\nabla P + \mu \Delta \textbf{v} \\
\rho \frac{De}{Dt} 
    &= \frac{\delta (\rho e)}{\delta t} + \nabla (\rho e \vv{\text{V}})
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Addendum:**
If you like to have more fancy box around equation, it might be that ˙\shadowbox`defined in the`fancybox` package is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{empheq, esvect}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}                                   % <---

%-------------- Show only equation. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{subequations}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2em}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
    \setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}
    \setlength\fboxsep{1ex}                             % <---
    \setlength\shadowsize{2pt}                          % <---
    \renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{RoyalBlue2}{white}}   % <---
    \definecolor{shadowcolor}{named}{RoyalBlue3}        % <---
\begin{empheq}[box = \shadowbox*]{align}                % <---
\frac{\delta \rho}{\delta t} +
    &\nabla (\rho v) = 0 \\
\rho \frac{D\textbf{v}}{Dt}
    &=-\nabla P + \mu \Delta \textbf{v} \\
\rho \frac{De}{Dt}
    &= \frac{\delta (\rho e)}{\delta t} + \nabla (\rho e \vv{\text{V}})
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't the OP want a thicker blue line? This is just the normal thickness.

Comment: Yes, but in preparation of this part of answer I was till to now interrupted. Now, I will finish this part .